# Why Bluetooth Microphone stops recording in Background Mode?

Tags: java, android, react-native, bluetooth

My goal is to record audio from a Bluetooth Microphone while in Background Mode.

Expected result:
The A2DPService records audio while in the background mode.

Actual result:
The A2DPService can not record audio after in the background mode after 2 minutes. The audio file will be empty.

How to reproduce the issue:

1. use the @ReactMethod `connectDevice(address: string)`.
2. went to background mode, wait until 2 minutes.
3. use the @ReactMethod `startBluetoothSco()` to record the audio
4. use the @ReactMethod `stopBluetoothSco()` to stop the recorder.
5. play the audio file. the audio file will not run as there is no input from the Bluetooth Microphone. Getting the app to Foreground Mode fixed the issue, but the app is intended to be used most of the time while in Background Mode.

A2DPService.java

```
package com.satpam.RNBluetoothNM.A2DP;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothA2dp;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class A2DPService {
    private BluetoothDevice mBluetoothDevice;
    private BluetoothA2dp mBluetoothA2dp;
    private AudioManager mAudioManager;

    public A2DPService(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager) reactContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        BluetoothAdapter
                .getDefaultAdapter()
                .getProfileProxy(reactContext, new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onServiceConnected(int i, BluetoothProfile bluetoothProfile) {
                        if (i == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
                            mBluetoothA2dp = (BluetoothA2dp) bluetoothProfile;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceDisconnected(int i) {
                        if (i == BluetoothProfile.A2DP) {
                            mBluetoothA2dp = null;
                        }
                    }
                }, BluetoothProfile.A2DP);
    }

    public boolean createBond(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        mBluetoothDevice = bluetoothDevice;
        return mBluetoothDevice.createBond();
    }

    public boolean connectA2DP(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        if (mBluetoothDevice == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            try {
                Method method = BluetoothA2dp.class.getMethod("connect", BluetoothDevice.class);
                method.invoke(mBluetoothA2dp, bluetoothDevice);
                return true;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getConnectedState() {
        return mBluetoothA2dp.getConnectionState(mBluetoothDevice);
    }

    public boolean startBluetoothSco() {
        if (getConnectedState() != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            return false;
        } else {
            mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
            mAudioManager.startBluetoothSco();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean stopBluetoothSco() {
        if (getConnectedState() != BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            return false;
        } else {
            mAudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
            mAudioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

RNBluetoothNM.java

```
package com.satpam.RNBluetoothNM;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableArray;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.satpam.RNBluetoothNM.A2DP.A2DPService;
import com.satpam.RNBluetoothNM.SPP.SPPService;

import java.util.Set;

public class RNBluetoothNMPackage extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "RNBluetoothNM";
    }

    private static final int getBondedDeviceRequestCode = 0;
    private Promise mPromise;

    private final ActivityEventListener activityListener = new BaseActivityEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == getBondedDeviceRequestCode && resultCode == activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getBondedDevices(mPromise);
                mPromise = null;
            }
        }
    };

    public RNBluetoothNMPackage(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);

        // Add a listener for `onActivityResult`
        reactContext.addActivityEventListener(activityListener);
    }

    private void _requestEnableBluetooth(Promise promise) {
        Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        Activity activity = getCurrentActivity();

        // Store the promise to resolve/reject when onActivityResult returns value;
        mPromise = promise;
        activity.startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, getBondedDeviceRequestCode);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getBondedDevices(final Promise promise) {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            promise.reject("getBondedDevices", "BluetoothAdapter is not supported");
        } else {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                _requestEnableBluetooth(promise);
            }

            Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            if (devices.size() > 0) {
                WritableArray array = Arguments.createArray();
                for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                    WritableMap writableMap = Arguments.createMap();
                    writableMap.putString("name", device.getName());
                    writableMap.putString("address", device.getAddress());
                    writableMap.putInt("bondState", device.getBondState());

                    array.pushMap(writableMap);
                }

                promise.resolve(array);
            }
        }
    }

    private A2DPService a2DPService;
    private SPPService sppService;

    @ReactMethod
    public void connectDevice(String address, final Promise promise) {
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            promise.reject("connectDevice", "BluetoothAdapter is not supported");
        } else {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                _requestEnableBluetooth(promise);
            }

            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
            a2DPService = new A2DPService(getReactApplicationContext());
            boolean a2dpIsBonded = a2DPService.createBond(bluetoothDevice);

            if (a2dpIsBonded == false) {
                promise.reject("A2DPService", "A2DP failed to bond");
            } else {
                boolean a2dpIsConnected = a2DPService.connectA2DP(bluetoothDevice);
                if (a2dpIsConnected == false) {
                    promise.reject("A2DP", "A2DP failed to connect");
                } else {

                    sppService = new SPPService(getReactApplicationContext());
                    boolean sppIsConnected = sppService.connectSPP(bluetoothDevice);
                    if (sppIsConnected == false) {
                        promise.reject("SPPService", "A2DP failed to bond");
                    } else {
                        promise.resolve(true);
                        Thread listener = new Thread(sppService);
                        listener.start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void startBluetoothSco(final Promise promise) {
        if (a2DPService == null) {
            promise.reject("startBluetoothSco", "A2DPService is null");
        } else {
            boolean isBluetoothScoStarted = a2DPService.startBluetoothSco();
            if (isBluetoothScoStarted == false) {
                promise.reject("startBluetoothSco", "A2DPService is not connected");
            } else {
                promise.resolve(true);
            }
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stopBluetoothSco(final Promise promise) {
        if (a2DPService == null) {
            promise.reject("stopBluetoothSco", "A2DPService is null");
        } else {
            boolean isBluetoothScoStopped = a2DPService.stopBluetoothSco();
            if (isBluetoothScoStopped == false) {
                promise.reject("stopBluetoothSco", "A2DPService is not connected");
            } else {
                promise.resolve(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a background service.  There's a limited amount of time those are allowed to run.  Use a foreground service, which has no time limitations.  This doesn't require your app to be in front, it just causes a notification to appear saying you're running.

The only things you need to change is to start the service with startForegroundService() and to call startForegound in the service itself.